# Switch case objects an get them through url parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm running an API in C# and started it as default webapi, so it gets the `/api/<controller>` url.

In my controller, I'm using `GET` method to retrieve some chart objects trough a switch case, but when testing on POSTMAN, both params work, but I get only the first object, and I can't seem to figure out why

Here's my controller

```
public class  GraphController : ApiController
{
    public Graph Get(string param)
    {

        //string[] arrayListGraphic = param.Split('|');

        switch (param)
        {
            // case "GF001": return new GraphDAO().graph01();
            case "GF002": return new GraphDAO().graph02();
            case "GF003": return new GraphDAO().graph03();
            // case "GF004": return new GraphDAO().graph04();
            // case "GF005": return new GraphDAO().graph04();
            // case "GF006": return new GraphDAO().graph01();

        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

so, the request comes as `localhost:xxxx/api/graph/?param=GF002&param=GF003`, But my response only gets me the first parameter data, when I wish to get all the parameters data!

What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: you should get 2 params in url but with different names, then your call would be public Graph Get(string param1, string param2) and your endpoint localhost:xxxx/api/graph?param1=GF002&param2=GF003

Comment: Parameters must have distinctive names.

Comment: Have you tried debugging this?  What does `param` look like when you pass it two values in the query string (`?param=GF002&param=GF003`).  Even if it came in as a collection of `GF002` and `GF003`, then what?  You'd need to loop over them, and then return the two graphs somehow.  Consider changing your API so that your query string looks something like `?param=GF002+GF003` (or use some other separator).

Comment: The current request will invoke one call and return the first match of param. You need to make two calls based on your implementation. One for each instance of param. Alternatively, as suggested above, use 2 params.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes You can assign multiple values to a parameter, but the get method must have the right signature to support it.

Comment: Still, if I use more than 1 parameter, how can I pass them to `switch(param)`?

Comment: You can change the action method signature like this: `public Graph Get(string[] params)` to accept multiple values as querystring parameter e.g. /?param=GF002&param=GF003

Comment: isn't http supposed to concatenate the values of parameter dupes with commas, or is that only a feature of POST?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I suggest:

```
public class  GraphController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<Graph> Get(string[] params)
    {

List<Graph> graphsList = new List<Graph>();

foreach(var param in params) {
        //string[] arrayListGraphic = param.Split('|');

        switch (param)
        {
            // case "GF001": return new GraphDAO().graph01();
            case "GF002": graphsList.Add(new GraphDAO().graph02()); break;
            case "GF003": graphsList.Add(new GraphDAO().graph03()); break;
            // case "GF004": return new GraphDAO().graph04();
            // case "GF005": return new GraphDAO().graph04();
            // case "GF006": return new GraphDAO().graph01();

        }


      }

       return graphsList;
    }
}
```

Call your API using url like:
http://localhost:xxxx/api/graph/?params=GF002&params=GF003

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it gets me `NullReferenceException` in the loop

Comment: @MatheusBatista Ah I think since I changed the input parameter name to `params` instead of `param` that’s why. You can try calling api  `localhost:xxxx/api/graph/?params=GF002&params=GF003`

Comment: @MatheusBatista Have you checked the updated answer and tried calling the api using the url I mentioned in the answer?

Comment: I did, but the VS won't even build the application, it gets me some NULL error in the `foreach(param in params)`

Comment: @MatheusBatista Can you paste the exception you are getting on building the project? Also, can you paste the api url that you are using for testing?

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing in more than one string to your controller, you're going to need to accept an array of strings rather than a single string like it is now. As it is, your url *should* be `localhost:xxxx/api/graph/?param=GF002`.

If you want to receive an both strings, you need to accept an array of strings in your controller action like

```
public Graph Get(string[] params) 
{
   //implementation
}
```

and you url should look like what you had it as.

Comment: I tried like this, but the switch(params) gives me the `can't convert string to string[]` in the cases

Comment: @MatheusBatista yes you'll have to loop thru the array and execute the switch for each string in the array. What is your goal of this function? to return a single `Graph` or a list of `Graphs`? If I have more insight as to this, I will be able to give a better solution for the implementation. Your original question only asked how to get both values from the url and making your api accept an array versus one string solves that problem

Comment: Actually, I want to display graphs based on the url param, I'm loading their data through the param `GF00X` in the js, and I want to load them ONLY if the param is passed, so I'm testing on postman trying to call more than one parameter to check if it's going to return me both data and only the called params.data

Comment: I'm still not quite following. Could you post your Js code on your OP too?

Comment: kk sorry for the trouble!! So, I have 1js file for each graph, and each one makes an ajax call to `    
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: window.location.protocol + "api/graph",
        data: { param: 'GF003' },
    })`

There's another API that will make a request to mine, an will pass as a parameter the graphs it want's to load, MINE must get those params and show only the requested ones, then load the data into the graphics, So if the param comes with more than one graphic, my api must display data for each graphic of the parameters